# Find $a$ given a function

Tags: functions, provability

> Given $f(x)=xe^{a \over x}, x>0$, for which it applies $f(x)\ge e^a, \forall x>0 
> $  (1)
>
> • Show that $a=1.$

**Personal work:**

Even by getting $e^a$ to the other side of the equation it still, does not remind $xe^{a\over x}$. I'm baffled on how to find $a$ with the given relationship (**(1)**).

Comment: @MrRipstein **Hint:** $x>0$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle f'(x)=e^\frac{a}{x}+xe^\frac{a}{x}\left(\frac{-a}{x^2}\right)=\frac{(x-a)e^\frac{a}{x}}{x}$.

$f'(x)>0$ for $x>a$ and $f'(x)<0$ for $0<x<a$.

$f$ attains its minimum at $x=a$.

So, $f(x)\ge f(a)=ae$ for $x>0$.

Therefore, $ae=e^a$.

Obviously, $a=1$ satisfies the relation.

It can be shown that $a=1$ is the only answer by considering the minimum value of $g(x)=e^x-ex$.